# ERROR UPDATE/MERGE must match at most one source row for each target row

Tags: database, google-bigquery

I have this error and I can't resolve it.

```sql
UPDATE TMP.PRUEBA_BT_PPP_MACA

  SET 
  precio_ppp = 
    CASE 
    WHEN A.precio_ppp = 0 AND B.PPP_FINAL_REALES <> "No encontrados" THEN CAST(B.PPP_FINAL_REALES AS NUMERIC)
    WHEN A.precio_ppp = 0 AND B.PPP_FINAL_REALES = "No encontrados"  THEN A.precio_ppp
    END,
  
  fuente_ppp = 
    CASE
    WHEN A.precio_ppp = 0 AND B.SKU = CAST(A.sap_sku AS STRING) AND B.CENTRO = A.centro_sap THEN 'PPP MLB'
    END

FROM L_ANALISIS_PPP_CONSOLIDADO B

INNER JOIN TMP.PRUEBA_BT_PPP_MACA A
ON A.precio_ppp = 0
AND A.site_id = 'MLB'
AND CAST(B.SKU AS INT) = A.sap_sku
AND B.CENTRO = A.centro_sap
AND A.centro_sap IN ('B','BR')
AND A.fecha BETWEEN '2023-06-01' and '2023-06-30'
 
WHERE 1 = 1
AND A.precio_ppp = 0
AND A.site_id = 'MLB'
AND B.SKU = CAST(A.sap_sku AS STRING)
AND B.CENTRO = A.centro_sap
AND A.centro_sap IN ('B','BR')
AND A.fecha BETWEEN '2023-06-01' and '2023-06-30'
```

I already created a tmp table using a distinct from the original table so I delete all the duplicated rows. So my table has no more duplicated rows, but I still got this problem when I'm trying to update with a join to the other table.

The other table doesn't have any duplicated row